# Failed to load package list -- have changed mirror server already

Tags: package-management, updates

For some weeks now I cannot do any updates or install any new programs in Ubuntu. This is the detail:

```
Failed to load the package list
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aheck_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1) 
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aheck_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aheck_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-all_Packages (1)
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aheck_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-en (1)
E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_aheck_ppa_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_i18n_Translation-es (1), W:You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E:The package cache file is corrupted
```

I already changed the mirror server but keeps sending the same message. I am not a very experienced user. Help please!

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt-get update`? Please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images. To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a mirror issue.

Read the error message carefully: You have corrupted files.

I recommend against using PPAs to users who do not understand apt error messages. PPAs are not supported software, and some can break your system.

Delete each file that cannot be parsed:

```
sudo rm -i /path/to/file
```

Next, refresh your package database:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then install updates:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I followed your instructions and now the computer runs like new. Being non familiar with terminals and run-commands, this was very helpful and clear. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ppa no longer maintained since years 2009, I don't understand why are you adding clearly abandoned ppa. Take a look at https://launchpad.net/~aheck/+archive/ubuntu/ppa, as you see there aren't any ppa compatible with 16.04.

Thus, a simple ppa remove would resolve this problem:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:aheck/ppa
sudo apt update
```